# Generate id for each list item generated by instafeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, instafeedjs

I'm using `instafeed.js` to get the latest instagram posts and I need an `id` generated for each list item. How can I do this?

JS:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    clientId: '<id>', //enter client id here
    limit: 5,
    sortBy: 'most-liked',
    //<div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div> ************************* likes count
    template: '<li><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" src="{{image}}"></li>'
});
feed.run();
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="instafeed"></ul>
```

Comment: you want to generate unique `id` each item feed by instafeed?

Comment: you can use class and find it using `eq`

Comment: You mean id for each `li` element in the `ul`

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes, that is exactly what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gordonbrander/2230317).

```
var ID = function () {
  return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
};
```

And then just call the function.

Comment: the id should not be random, as it should later be used to modify the element with css. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `{{id}}` keyword

```js
var feed = new Instafeed({
  clientId: '<id>', //enter client id here
  limit: 5,
  sortBy: 'most-liked',
  template: '<li id="{{id}}"><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" src="{{image}}"></li>'
});
feed.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.imnjb.me/libs/instafeed.js/1.3.2/instafeed.js"></script>
<ul id="instafeed"></ul>
```